# RxSwift - Retry network request with maxCount until success

Tags: swift, rx-swift

How can I retry network requesting with maxCount (some sort of failure), eg. 5 times or until the server is returning something of what I want using RxSwift's `retry` operator.

What I suppose to do is:

1. when success became "ok", stop retrying and emit `queryedSuccess` immediately
2. when success is still yet "fail", continue retrying until maxCount reaches 5 and emit `queryedFail`

The struct of JSON return from server looks like this:

```
struct QueryAlipayOrderEnvelope {
    var success: String // "ok" or "fail"
    var tradeNumber: String
}
```

Here is what I attempt to do:

```
struct ViewModel {

    var viewWillAppearTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var rechargeTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var outTradeNumber = PublishSubject<String>()

    var queryedSuccess: Driver<QueryAlipayOrderEnvelope>
    var queryedFail: Driver<QueryAlipayOrderEnvelope>

    let queryResult = self.outTradeNumber.asObservable()
        .flatMapLatest { tradeNum in
            AppEnvironment.current.apiService.queryAlipayOrder(outTradeNumber: tradeNum).materialize().debug("queryAlipayOrder", trimOutput: true)
        }
        .share(replay: 1)
        .retry(5)

    self.queryedSuccess = queryResult
        .elements()
        .skipWhile { $0.success != "ok" }
        .takeLast(1)
        .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .never())
        .debug("queryedSuccess", trimOutput: true)

    // this will emit when all 5 `success` are `fail`
    self.queryedFail = queryResult
        .elements()
        .takeLast(1)
        .filter { $0.success != "ok" }
        .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .never())
        .debug("queryedFail", trimOutput: true)
}
```

However, the request only called once and being disposed without any retrying.

Comment: `share` might be the culprit here. Do you need it?

Comment: @Cristik If I remove `share`, request will be called for each subscribes.(so this is not the issue here.)

Answer (score 0):

The Retry operator responds to an `onError` notification. Because you are using `materialize()` in your `flatMapLatest`, you are turning your `Observable<Element>` into a `Observable<Event<Element>>`, meaning you are receiving element that tells you it was an error event instead of receiving `onError` notification.

Try to remove `materialize()` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, this is still doesn't work.

Comment: So removing the materialize() will receive error and trigger retry. How  can I add a middle layer to return an error so that the request will throw error if need? cause I need to check the `success` identifer

Comment: Well, `AppEnvironment.current.apiService.queryAlipayOrder` should return an Observable that can error out. Take a look here: https://www.netguru.co/codestories/networking-with-rxswiftit